# Is there a way to parse the subject line that it will go to multiple folders

Tags: development, incoming-email

I am emailing a report to sharepoint.  I am grouping by subject.

The subject is coded like this:

```
830/862:IBM
```

Is there a way to parse the subject line that it will go to multiple folders.  Right now it uses the full subject line and I would like it to first go in a folder named `830/862` and then under that a folder `IBM`

Answer (score 0):

A workflow seems the right tool - you should be able to have it parse the field and move to a particular folder based on what it finds. You can have it set to go to the root, and the workflow would analyze it and move it from there.

You want it to go to a subfolder in a folder, as opposed to into two different folders, if I read your question right. If you wanted it to go go to a number of folders, you'd copy it as opposed to move, but the process should be the same. Using the colon as the delimiter seems the right place to start.